# lookup and add a related data from database into another excel sheet

Tags: excel

I have a database (excel sheet) and a smaller sheet with a some names from that big database. I want to lookup the related price (from the database) and add it infront of its name (into the small sheet). How could I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the VLOOKUP formula.